# Compiling error of VLC project in iOS

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, vlc

I am trying to compile the VLC project for iOS, following the [instruction](https://wiki.videolan.org/iOSCompile) step by step.

```
git clone git://git.videolan.org/vlc-ports/ios.git
sh buildAspenProject.sh -s -k 7.0
```

And I get this compiling error:

```
cd builds/unix; /bin/sh ./configure  '--without-png' '--prefix=/Users/change/Desktop/VLC_Library/ios/ImportedSources/vlc/contrib/i686-apple-darwin11-i386' '--build=i686-apple-darwin10' '--host=i686-apple-darwin11' '--target=i686-apple-darwin11' '--program-prefix=' '--enable-static' '--disable-shared' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--with-pic'
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --disable-dependency-tracking
checking build system type... i686-apple-darwin10
checking host system type... i686-apple-darwin11
checking for i686-apple-darwin11-gcc... xcrun clang
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... yes
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether xcrun clang accepts -g... yes
checking for xcrun clang option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... xcrun cc -E
checking for i686-apple-darwin10-gcc... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking for suffix of native executables... rm: conftest.dSYM: is a directory
ld: building for MacOSX, but linking against dylib built for iOS Simulator file '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.dylib' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
configure: error: native C compiler is not working
make[1]: *** [setup] Error 1
make: *** [.freetype2] Error 2
```

The environment:

```
XCode 5.0
MountainLion 10.8.4
iPhoneSimulator SDK 7.0
```

The invocation

```
$ ld -v
@(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-224.1
configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 i386 x86_64 armv6m armv7m armv7em
LTO support using: LLVM version 3.3svn, from Apple Clang 5.0 (build 500.2.75)
```

How do I fix this problem?
Appreciate if any suggestion or idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known problem with Xcode 5 for which I don't have a fix yet.

To workaround, go to ImportedSources/vlc/contrib/iPhoneSimulator-i386 and run "make .freetype2". Afterwards, go back to the top directory and run the buildAspen script again.

Note that you'll need to do the same thing (with "iPhoneOS-armv7" and "iPhoneOS-armv7s" respectively) if you decide to compile for iOS devices at a later point.

I hope to fix this shortly. Enjoy hacking VLC for iOS!

Answer (score 1):

That got me further but got stumped by missing download URL for `modplug-xmms`.

VLC is insisting on downloading a copy of the source from

```
MODPLUG_GIT_HASH := 9b08cc646c3dc94dd446ab0671e3427dae8a83fc
MODPLUG_URL := http://sourceforge.net/code-snapshots/git/m/mo/modplug-xmms/git.git/modplug-xmms-git-$(MODPLUG_GIT_HASH).zip
```

which does not exist as of this time. (Server down?)

I did find of the copy of the source under

```
http://sourceforge.net/projects/modplug-xmms/files/latest/download/libmodplug-0.8.8.4.tar.gz
```

I downloaded it and installed it manually:

../ios/ImportedSources/vlc/contrib/iPhoneSimulator-i386/libmodplug

Comment: Yes, I also encounter with this problem after resolving my original stuck one. I get the modplug-xmms file and put it in my dropbox here(https://www.dropbox.com/s/v2i55agdwe660ri/modplug-xmms-git-9b08cc646c3dc94dd446ab0671e3427dae8a83fc.zip). Put this file in ~/ios/ImportedSources/vlc/contrib/tarballs thus the script can keep going on.
Hope that these experiences can save someone's time if he/she wants to compile VLC for iOS. Compiling VLC for iOS is such painful.
ps. using the xmms file in my dropbox on your risk.

Comment: Fixed this last night. I just need to update the libvlc hash in ios.git, which will be done in a few minutes from now.