# VLC-2.2 SDK for Xcode 5 + iOS7 + 10.9 not compiled

Tags: ios7, xcode5, vlc, osx-mavericks

```
FreeType build system -- automatic system detection

The following settings are used:

  platform                    unix
  compiler                    xcrun clang
  configuration directory     ./builds/unix
  configuration rules         ./builds/unix/unix.mk

If this does not correspond to your system or settings please remove the file
`config.mk' from this directory then read the INSTALL file for help.

Otherwise, simply type `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make' again to build the library,
or `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make refdoc' to build the API reference (the latter needs python).

cd builds/unix; /bin/sh ./configure  '--without-png' '--prefix=/Users/itux/Developer/GIT/ios/ImportedSources/vlc/contrib/arm-apple-darwin11-armv7' '--build=i686-apple-darwin10' '--host=arm-apple-darwin11' '--target=arm-apple-darwin11' '--program-prefix=' '--enable-static' '--disable-shared' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--with-pic'
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --disable-dependency-tracking
checking build system type... i686-apple-darwin10
checking host system type... arm-apple-darwin11
checking for arm-apple-darwin11-gcc... xcrun clang
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/itux/Developer/GIT/ios/ImportedSources/vlc/contrib/iPhoneOS-armv7/freetype/builds/unix':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
make[1]: *** [setup] Error 77
make: *** [.freetype2] Error 2
```

I try build freetype2 as description here:
[VLC Compiling Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19174942/compiling-error-of-vlc-project-in-ios)

Comment: After install "libtool", "autoconf", "automake" in brew, and restart build script, i see that: http://pastebin.com/6T2NQeXq

Comment: Do you use the build script provided in iOS.git?

Comment: Yes, i'm use provided build script